# Search across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using this Mysql query:

```
WHERE fname LIKE '%{$query}%' OR lname LIKE '%{$query}%' OR zipcode LIKE '%{$query}%' OR city LIKE '%{$query}%'
```

Let's say I have the following info in my database:

- First Name: Bill
- Last Name: Gates
- Zipcode: 12345 AA
- City: New York

When I search for 'New York', I get the expected result (bill gates), But when I search for "bill new york' I get no results.

What is the correct query to search across multiple columns?

Comment: Is your table InnoDB?

Comment: And why does that make you wonder? You queried for a string `bill new york` and none of the columns contained that. You got the result for `new york` because one column had *exactly* that string in. There are no correct ways, there's a way that gives you data and the way that doesn't. Using `LIKE` for searches is bad because it's not just slow - it's, as you experienced, difficult to implement correctly. Google about using FULLTEXT indexes and searches (it works with InnoDB storage engine) to see how people search for multiple words in multiple columns.

Comment: @mihai Yes InnoDB it is

Comment: Whats your mysql version?

Comment: @Mihai Server version: 5.5.31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using LIKE in your statement against a column you are saying compare all of "bill new york" against City "New York" which will fail because the phrase "bill" was in the query and not in the column.

In this instance you are better of using MySQL's FULLTEXT searching like below;

```
SELECT FieldName, 
MATCH (FieldName) AGAINST (+"Bill New York" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance
FROM MyTable
WHERE MATCH (FieldName) AGAINST (+"Bill New York" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING Relevance > 0
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```

If you can provide your table structures I can expand on the answer.

Comment: The table is InnoDB so fullsearch is out.

Comment: @Mihai InnoDB support for FULLTEXT indexes is available in MySQL 5.6.4 and higher. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is that LIKE is basically just case insesative version of =

there are two ways you can go about what you are trying to do, the firsat would be to explode you r $query on saces and use a seires of LIKE's for each work found, this is messy and i wouldnt advise it.

the seccond more preferable option is to use a full text search MATCH() AGAINST() it is far simpler and makes for much cleaner code
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html <- this is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

You either need to parse the query into separate words and dynamically construct a looooong WHERE clause that searches each field for each word separately, ORing them together.

OR

You use FULLTEXT indexing.

I would suggest the latter.